# Using ARRAY_LITERAL can't find my mistake

Tags: date, google-sheets

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT G, H, I, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE G >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0);QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT R, S, T, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE R >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0);QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT U, V, W, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE U >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0);QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT X, Y, Z, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE X >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0);QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT AA, AB, AC, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE AA >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)}),1,TRUE,2,TRUE)
```

This is a sample of my code to arrange by date.  I keep getting #VALUE! in my cell.  This worked last year and all of a sudden it quit.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/106ScDEWhDQlFdIV-1uBC2PrR1m1KUjIir_IX3yDhIHs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

one of your queries does not output anything... use:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({
 IFERROR(QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT G, H, I, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE G >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0), IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,13)/0));
 IFERROR(QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT R, S, T, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE R >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0), IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,13)/0));
 IFERROR(QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT U, V, W, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE U >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0), IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,13)/0));
 IFERROR(QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT X, Y, Z, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE X >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0), IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,13)/0));
 IFERROR(QUERY('Facility Use Requests'!A2:AC, "SELECT AA, AB, AC, J, C, F, K, L, D, E, P, N, O WHERE AA >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0), IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,13)/0))}),1,TRUE,2,TRUE)
```

[image]